# Annihilation and Creation Operators in Nonlinear Dynamics

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I am reading Introduction in Nonlinear Dynamics for Physicists and I am confused by the section on annihilation and creation operators being used in analyzing oscillators.

When analyzing the equations

$\frac{dx}{dt} = y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = -x + \mu[-q(x)y+f(x)]$

They introduce the complex variable $a(t)$ and make the substution:

$x(t)=a(t)*e^{it}+a^**e^{-it}$

$y(t)=i*a(t)*e^{it}-i*a^**e^{-it}$

They then make the substitution and have terms like $q(a,a^*,e^{\pm it})$

I have two questions:

Why is this substitution made?

What does the notation $q(a,a^*,e^{\pm it})$ mean?